# fade a div element infinite

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

need fade multiple div elements that contains text and image inside, need fade this div in a infinite fade, like a slide show. anyone can help me? need be like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/JbrXd/

```
<div class="fios-cobre">
    <div id="first-content">
        ... 
    </div><!-- /#first-content -->
    <div id="second-content">
        ...
    </div><!-- /#second-content -->
</div><!-- /.fios-cobre -->
```

Comment: looks like it's working, aside from one missing image

Comment: WHAT? why i have -2? well...but, this works only for images

Comment: Oh I see. I think you've been downvoted because you didn't even attempt a solution on your own. You could try pretending the *-content divs are like images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, next time attempt your own solution first. But for the time being, maybe this will help..

HTML & CSS

```
<head>
<style>
div.fios-cobre {
position: relative;
}

div.fios-cobre > div {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="fios-cobre">
  <div id="first-content">
    first 
  </div><!-- /#first-content -->
  <div id="second-content">
    second
  </div><!-- /#second-content -->
  <div id="third-content">
    third
  </div><!-- /#second-content -->
</div><!-- /.fios-cobre -->
```

images can also go in with the text, if you want (first, second, third)

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.fios-cobre div:gt(0)').hide();

    setInterval(function(){
    $('div.fios-cobre div:first-child').fadeOut()
        .next('div').fadeIn()
        .end().appendTo('div.fios-cobre');}, 
    3000);              
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/54xkj/

Comment: Yes, it can go inside <body>.  :)

Comment: just make sure you reference a jquery library in the <head> of your page.  something like this..  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>